# Julia Plots has no output in Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia, plots.jl

I'm trying to plot a geometric sum (for teaching purposes), and am getting no output for certain input values.
This is run using Julia 1.3 on MacOS Mojave 10.14.5 using an up-to-date version of Chrome

Here is the code:

```
using Plots
geom_series(x,n)=sum([x.^m for m in 0:n])

n=14
x=LinRange(-2.0,4.0,1001)
y=geom_series(x,n)
plot(x,y, ylims=(-10,10))
```

This plots fine in Jupyter notebook for n in 1:13. Thereafter, it plots for any *odd* n, but for no *even* n. It will also plot if I reduce the domain (e.g. x= LinRange(-2.0,2.0,1001)) or if I remove the ylims from the plot statement.

This involves some very large y-values, for both odd and even n. I've checked for NaNs, but there aren't any.

It also runs perfectly well if I run the code in the REPL.

Also no problems if I use PyPlot instead of Plots, so it is not a serious issue for me.

But does anyone have some idea of what might be going on?

Comment: Hey, trying to get my notebook environment up and running to test this out. It did work fine in the Repl for me so I'll get back to you when I can run notebooks locally again.